# Proxy configuration to load all images from a folder

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, magnolia

I am using Magnolia 5.4 and i am trying to provide proxy pass settings to magnolia pages using apache http server. And i have configured like this

```
    ProxyPass /travel http://<ip address>:8080/magnoliaPublic/travel.html
    ProxyPass /.resources/** http://<ip address>:8080/.resources/**
```

the travel configuration is working, but not giving images and css files. So need a configuration to load all images and files that have .resources in path. how can i achieve this? Thaks

Comment: why people with half minded always down vote. what wrong in the question. add comment so that i understand

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To remove `/magnoliaPublic` context path from the URL? I.e. you want the `http://your.domain.com/travel` URL to give you the content of `http://your.tomcat.ip.address:8080/magnoliaPublic/travel.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to load folders,but to load images you can use following configuration using **ProxyPassMatch**

```
     ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.png)$" "http://<ip address>:8080/$1"
     ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.jpeg)$" "http://<ip address>:8080/$1"
     ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.jpg)$" "http://<ip address>:8080/$1"
     ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.img)$" "http://<ip address>:8080/$1"
```

With the above configuration, the apache server forward the requests that have extensions .png, .jpeg, .jpg, .img to the specified url.

Refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch for more information